# What is the difference between dispatchEvent() and triggerEventHandler() in angular unit testing using karma?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing unit test for a directive(called on input event), which is modifying an input value on a formControl. I've created a test component in my spec file for the same. I noticed a difference between triggerEventHandler() and dispatchEvent(), while dispatchEvent() was triggering the event correctly and directive was triggered, in the case of triggerEventHandler() event wasn't triggered. Can anyone let me know, what's the difference between them, apart from that dispatchEvent() is called on nativeElement.

```
// directive
export class AlphaNumericCheckDirective {

  constructor(private ctrl: NgControl) {
  }
  @HostListener('input')
  onInputChange() {
    const pattern = /[^0-9]/g;
    const elVal = (this.ctrl.control as AbstractControl).value;
    if (pattern.test(elVal)) {
      const newVal = elVal.replace(pattern, '');
      (this.ctrl.control as AbstractControl).setValue(newVal);
    }
  }
}

// relevant code of test
it('should allow only numerics', () => {
   const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
   const inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
   (fixture.componentInstance.testGroup.get('testControl') as 
   AbstractControl).patchValue('12a');
   inputEl.triggerEventHandler('input', null); // not triggering the directive
   inputEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); // triggering the directive
});
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide a minimal working example as a stackblitz for example than it‘s easier to understand where the problem is and help you. My first guess is that after using triggerEventHandler you should wait for the event to have been finished with a fakeAsync test setup and tick(). But not having seen the whole example this is just a first guess.

Answer (score 7):

`triggerEventHandler` belongs to Angular. The `triggerEventHandler` will invoke the event handler only if it was declared on the native element by using `Angular event bindings`, the `@HostListener()` or `@Output` decorators.

`dispatchEvvent` comes in handy when we define events via `JS native APIs`, for eg. RxJS `fromEvent` observable, etc.

We can even use `dispatchEvent` to simulate Angular Material component's event while testing, as `triggerEventHandler` would not work there since Angular doesn’t know about those events.

Here's a very interesting article that will help you understand the difference neatly https://netbasal.com/simulating-events-in-angular-unit-tests-5482618cd6c6

Comment: got your point, but i've used @HostListener() on the directive, then why triggerEventHandler is not working?

Comment: I have read the article, I know the difference, but I see no advantage in using `triggerEventHandler`, it is more verbose and you need to call change detection yourself. Meanwhile `dispatchEvent` work with everything.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed same issue as well. What I found is triggerEventHandler() works in the button testing scenario but not the input case while dispatchevent works in the input scenario which is your case.