# How to delete a character from input field in Angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, keyboard-events, angular8

I'm trying to do a very basic unit test to test that pressing backspace in a text field will delete the character. However, I've tried all sorts of ways of triggering the events but it does not seem to actually delete anything. What I have so far is below, it's based on the spec files from this library https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/blob/develop/src/app/ngx-mask/test/delete.spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
  <input type="text" (keydown)="keydown()"
    (focus)="focus()"
    (blur)="blur()"
    (input)="input()" id="testField" [formControl]="formField" />`,
})
class TestInputComponent {

  public formField: FormControl;

  constructor() {
    this.formField = new FormControl('ABCDE');
  }

  keydown() { console.error('keydown called'); }
  input() { console.error('input called'); }
  focus() { console.error('focus called'); }
  blur() { console.error('blur called'); }
}

describe('Delete Characters', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestInputComponent>;
  let component: TestInputComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestInputComponent],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestInputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should delete a character and move cursor back', () => {
    const debugElement: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    const inputTarget: HTMLInputElement = debugElement.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    spyOnProperty(document, 'activeElement').and.returnValue(inputTarget);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    inputTarget.value = 'ABCDE';
    inputTarget.selectionStart = 3;
    inputTarget.selectionEnd = 3;
    debugElement.triggerEventHandler('keydown', { code: 'Backspace', keyCode: 8, target: inputTarget });
    debugElement.triggerEventHandler('input', { target: inputTarget });

    expect(inputTarget.selectionStart).toEqual(2); // Fails, is still 3
    expect(inputTarget.value).toEqual('ABDE'); // Fails, is still ABCDE
  });

});
```

Comment: I think you need to allow for an Angular CD cycle to run between the input event and when you check `value`.  Does it work if you add in `fixture.detectChanges` between the event and the assert?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately have tried that and no luck

Answer (score 1):

Your triggerEventHandler is not triggering event. Please replace triggerEventHandler with dispatchEvent, and try.

```
   debugElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'), { code: 'Backspace', keyCode: 8, target: inputTarget });
    debugElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'), { target: inputTarget });
```

Please refer to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084557/9016028).

Comment: Hi, I have tried that and it's the same result. Actually both ways appear to be triggering the events as the console.error logs are appearing for both keydown and input